# Cding into directory hangs terminal

Tags: linux, shell, ls, cd

I am encountering a really weird issue when trying to "cd" into a specific directory (e.g. directory_A) along a path. Whenever I try to "cd", my linux terminal immediately hangs for at least 1hr. Upon entering successfully, the terminal is completely frozen and I cannot run any commands within the shell.

Additionally, while exiting the "cd" command during execution through  "ctrl-c" does kill the "cd" call, it becomes impossible to run any additional command within the shell (i.e. "ls/cd/etc.." into directory_B causes the terminal to hang again). This happens despite the fact that cding into directory_B (without first trying to cd into directory A) causes no issues whatsoever. It appears that trying to enter directory_A at all causes immediate failure of the shell somehow.

What is more is that "lsing" directory A from its parent dir causes no issues. I can see all the files (and even open them! - e.g. through "vim directory_A/foo.txt), but "cding" causes massive problems.

I'm not sure if I just have the wrong keyword searches, but I haven't been able to find similar issues - though I acknowledge I am far from an expert with these things.

Has anyone seen such an issue before? Or may know potentially where to search for potential answers?

I'd be happy to provide any other information as well - thanks very much for any help/advice you may have!

Comment: is `cd` an alias or function which does something else?

Comment: Run `env -i bash --norc` and try again in the resulting shell. I'm guessing this works fine, and that the problem is in a customized `cd`, `PROMPT_COMMAND`, `PS1` or similar.

Comment: Thank you! Both ```bash --noprofile --norc``` as pwoolvett and ```env -i bash --norc``` work completely fine as you suggested. It seems like running it within my ```zsh``` environment is causing the issue, yet the "type cd" command says "cd is a shell builtin" and "alias | grep cd" returns
```alias | grep cd
-='cd -'
1='cd -1'
2='cd -2'
3='cd -3'
4='cd -4'
5='cd -5'
6='cd -6'
7='cd -7'
8='cd -8'
9='cd -9'
gcd='git checkout $(git_develop_branch)'
grt='cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel || echo .)"'```

Do you know if these are expected results? Thanks so much for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) type `alias | grep cd` to see if its aliased, or `type cd` to check wether its been re-defined as a function.

B) start a new shell without startup file: `bash --noprofile --norc`

C) use a different shell: `sh`, or whatever

Comment: Thank you! I've posted a comment above about the results from (A), and (B) works completely fine. I am using a "zsh" shell typically - does this behavior mean that somewhere my zsh shell is remapping my "cd" to something weird? I really appreciate all the help and taking the time and everything.

Comment: I don't use zsh, but I'd start looking at startup files like `~/.zshrc` and stuff like oh-my-zsh (if you use that).  A quick google showed https://blog.praveen.science/oh-my-zsh-cheat-sheet/, which looks looks familiar... So I'd try either disabling a specific puglin or re-installing the oh-my-zsh